Why does BeautifulSoup output self-closing tags in HTML?
I've tried with 3 different parsers: lxml, html5lib, html.parser
All of them output invalid HTML:
>>> BeautifulSoup('<br>', 'html.parser')
<br/>
>>> BeautifulSoup('<br>', 'lxml')
<html><body><br/></body></html>
>>> BeautifulSoup('<br>', 'html5lib')
<html><head></head><body><br/></body></html>
>>> BeautifulSoup('<br>', 'html.parser').prettify()
'<br/>\n'

All of them have /> "self-closing" void tags.
How can I get BeautifulSoup to output HTML that has void tags without />?

Why do you think it is invalid HTML? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags states that "there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/) [...] On void elements, it does not mark the start tag as self-closing but instead is unnecessary and has no effect of any kind." I.e. for HTML it is allowed but unnecessary.

Use the html5 formatter:

If you pass in formatter="html5", it’s the same as formatter="html", but Beautiful Soup will omit the closing slash in HTML void tags like “br”:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BeautifulSoup('<br>', 'html.parser').decode(formatter="html5")

Which outputs:
'<br>'


As a frame challenge:
You do not need to remove the / because the output is valid HTML and, since the tags are void elements, they are not considered to be self-closing.


All of them have /> "self-closing" void tags.

Referring to the HTML specification:

13.1.2.1 Start tags
Start tags must have the following format:

The first character of a start tag must be a U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN character (<).
The next few characters of a start tag must be the element's tag name.
If there are to be any attributes in the next step, there must first be one or more ASCII whitespace.
Then, the start tag may have a number of attributes, the syntax for which is described below. Attributes must be separated from each other by one or more ASCII whitespace.
After the attributes, or after the tag name if there are no attributes, there may be one or more ASCII whitespace. (Some attributes are required to be followed by a space. See the attributes section below.)
Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/), which on foreign elements marks the start tag as self-closing. On void elements, it does not mark the start tag as self-closing but instead is unnecessary and has no effect of any kind. For such void elements, it should be used only with caution — especially since, if directly preceded by an unquoted attribute value, it becomes part of the attribute value rather than being discarded by the parser.
Finally, start tags must be closed by a U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN character (>).


The specification explicitly states that for void elements, a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/), immediately before the closing U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN character (>):

is allowed;
is unnecessary (having no effect of any kind); and
does not mark the tag as self-closing.

Therefore, in HTML, <br/> is valid HTML and is not a self-closing tag but is equivalent to <br> and the / character should be ignored.

Why do you think BeautifulSoup adds those solidi? I think it's terrible, because it makes the string larger, and it looks less like human-written, human-readable HTML.

@Nils The output with / is valid HTML and also valid XHTML and XML. Without the / it is only valid HTML.

Good point — hadn't realised that before reading pankaj's answer. Thanks for your answer I've upvoted it, and thanks for your comment on pankaj's answer
